# Wildfly get datasource parameters

Tags: jdbc, datasource, wildfly

Is it possible to get values of datasource parameters, as they are configured in the standalone.xml? Namely, I need the password and username.

Comment: Why do you need the username and password?

Comment: to use some other Oracle services that need access to the same schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do that with jboss-cli. Given the example data source, you read attributes this way:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:read-attribute(name=user-name)
```

complete example:

```
jboss-cli.bat

You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] embed-server
[standalone@embedded /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:read-attribute(name=user-name)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "sa"
}
[standalone@embedded /] /subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:read-attribute(name=password)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "sa"
}
```

There are some examples at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes